# Select entire row based on a max value of a field - without nesting

Tags: sql, select, max

```
select * 
from webOrders
where lastModifiedDate in (select max (lastModifiedDate) from webOrders)
```

Is there a simpler way without nesting the selects?

Doing something like this also results in an error:

```
select id, amount, quantity, max(lastModifiedDate) from webOrders.
```

Comment: also note: `order` could be a reserved keyword in your sql flavor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches, depending on your needs.

If you only need one row returned, you can sort on the column of interest and return the top row.  For example:

```
select top 1 * 
from `order`
order by last_modified_date desc
```

if you use SQL Server or

```
select * 
from `order`
order by last_modified_date desc
limit 1
```

if you use MySQL.

If you need to get one row **per group**, then you do typically have to use a subquery or a join.

Comment: This of course assumes SQL Server right?  mySql and Postgres would use `LIMIT 1` and Oracle would use `WHERE ROWNUM = 1`

Comment: Great just what I was looking for. Thank you Matt and Mike. I use Oracle so the query was - select * 
from `order`where rownum=1 
order by last_modified_date desc

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOP 1 * from [order] order by lastModifiedDate desc
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do select

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM XXX
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp